# ClassNotFoundException for a class available in one of the jar from BOOT-INF/lib

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, classpath

I have 2 spring-boot maven projects. The first project creates an extra jar using maven-jar-plugin, the pom.xml plugin part is as below.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>beans</classifier>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/models/*</include>
                    <include>**/exceptions/*</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This creates "sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-beans.jar" and also upload as artifact.

The 2nd project is referring the above jar as a dependency. The pom.xml of 2nd project contains

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>beans</classifier>
</dependency>
```

The build output of the 2nd project is an executable jar. when I explode this jar, it has BOOT-INF\lib and that lib contains sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-beans.jar.

However, when I execute 2nd project, it throws

```
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.sample.models.AData not present
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperclass(ClassRepository.java:104)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperclass(ClassRepository.java:86)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:955)
at org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference.<init>(ParameterizedTypeReference.java:52)
at com.sample.util.DataCacheUtil$1.<init>(DataCacheUtil.java:50)
at com.sample.util.DataCacheUtil.getAData(DataCacheUtil.java:50)
```

I really do not get what is missing here, please help me out!

Comment: Why does it create a supplemental jar? via Maven-jar-plugin?

Comment: Because, somehow I am not allowed to create a new maven project for the common POJOs, so I created an extra jar to avoid copying those in the 2nd project.

Comment: you can create multi-module project, no? the first project with two submodules (pojo + boot app). otherwise your beans would share ALL dependencies of the main project

Comment: on the subject - you can debug and trace such problem in your IDE. most probably you have an issue with class-loaders or their order. if you know the correct one - just use it with Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(...)